# Query where one option can have several values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I need select all records from db where one option(for example `user_id`) can be same of possible values (`1,2 or 3`). And then order by date(for example).

I need something like this as a result:

```
records:
  id: 1, user_id: 1
  id: 2, user_id: 1
  id: 3, user_id: 2
  id: 4, user_id: 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Model.where(user_id: [1, 2, 3]).order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: See the docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html for more answers like this one.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID IN (1, 2, 4);